# SVGs won't pick up correct font in Angular project

Tags: angular, svg, webfonts

Working with SVG images in an Angular project and the fonts default to times roman instead of using the appropriate webfont.  They only work if you have the font installed on your system.  Seems to only effect SVG images though, all text on the site uses the correct font. Any workarounds for this?

Comment: I think this is a "known" limitation of SVG. I am also researching this topic as I wanted to learn how to do arbitrary fonts in SVG. Let me know if you find something:) I will share my  findings asap.

Comment: I started with https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/SVG_fonts and will be trying to leverage external font references.

Comment: What does "working with SVG images" mean exactly?  Are you inlining the SVG in the HTML, or using something like `<img>`? The former should work, but that latter will not.